# How to render URIs safely in erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, url, erb

I have tried a variety of escaping and unescaping options, but don't understand why my erb is not rendering properly.

I have standard picture url in the format:

```
 https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pB-5XG-DbAA/hqdefault.jpg;
```

entered into my controller as the following:

```
@whats_hot_last_vid = @whats_hot_last.video.picture
```

When I try to render it in my js.erb file:

```
var lastsongImg = <%= @whats_hot_last_vid %>;
```

Here's how it renders:

```
var lastsongImg = https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pB-5XG-DbAA/hqdefault.jpg;
```

From what I can see, it renders '//' in the http address as the beginning of a JS comment, leading to raising various errors like

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to convert your string `to_json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to deal with variables like this in js blocks in erb is to use `.to_json`.  This works with strings, arrays, and hashes (which it will convert to json objects).  Basically it does the "right thing", and you don't need to worry about wrapping extra formatting around it depending on what type of object it is.

```
//string
var lastsongImg = <%= @whats_hot_last_vid.to_json %>;
// => var lastsongImg = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pB-5XG-DbAA/hqdefault.jpg";

//arrays
<% myArray = [1, "abc", 1.6] %>;
var myArrayJs = <%= myArray.to_json %>;
// => var myArrayJs = [1, "abc", 1.6];

//hashes
<% myHash = {:foo => "bar", :chunky => "bacon"} %>;
var myObject = <%= myHash.to_json %>;
// => var myObject = {"chunky":"bacon","foo":"bar"};
```

EDIT:  as a side note, ActiveRecord objects have the to_js method as well, and produce an object like this:

```
{"car":{"id":123 "color":"red", "make":"Ford", "model": "Mondeo"}}
```

You can of course overwrite this for particular models if you want.

Comment: This works within js.erb itself. But how do I pass an array from Ruby to JS? I have in my controller /at/users = [['Jon', 'student', 18],['Fred', 'teacher', 36]]     In Js, using var myArray = <%= /at/users.to_json %> creates an unholy mess where it appears unescaped, full of strange characters

Comment: What is `/at/users` here?  Is it a variable name?  Because it looks illegal.

Comment: Hi yes SO won't let me write usual 'at' sign as it thinks I am alerting a user, so I improvised an /at/

Comment: Use backticks, like `@users` which is written in the comments as \`@users\`

Answer (score 2):

You have to put qoutes around the string, like this

```
var lastsongImg = "<%= @whats_hot_last_vid %>";
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: Thanks, can't believe i missed this one :)